# Reset form on onclick function

Tags: forms, reset

I have a problem. I want to have an reset/clear button in my form, but it won''t work..

http://pastebin.com/jc0yqXiq

Line 1-8 is the php for my form on line 94-97

```
  <form id="myForm" method="post" action="" onSubmit="if(!confirm('Är du säker på att du vill acceptera budet?')){return false;}">
   <input type='text' value="1" value='<?php echo $doors ?>' name='doors[<?php echo $auto->ID; ?>]'>
   <input type="button" onclick="" value="Neka bud"> - <input type='submit' value='Godkänn bud' />
</form>

<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['doors'] ) ){  
// verify nounce prob a good idea
    foreach($_POST['doors'] as $item=>$key) {
        $id= sanitize_text_field($item);
        update_post_meta( $id, 'doors', sanitize_text_field( $key ) );
    }  
}
?>
```

Any suggestions to what the problem might be :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a reset button you have to include a reset input in the form:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset!">
```

This element resets all form values to **default** values.

In your example

```
<input type="button" onclick="" value="Neka bud"> - <input type='submit' value='Godkänn bud' />
<input type="reset" value="Reset!">
</form>
```

Comment: yes but i want to reset the default value, my default value is "1" and yes i know that i can use placeholder but thats not an option :)

Comment: Then you have to reset the values using Javascript.

Comment: first I'll tell you that code of text field is wrong. you can't add 2 values in one field. `value="1" value='<?php echo $doors ?>'` should be `value="1"` or `value='<?php echo $doors ?>'`